# ODBC trace that has been activated but how can I deactivate it?

Tags: windows-7, postgresql, odbc

My colleague has activated an odbc trace to troubleshoot the issue we currently have.

But alas he has created another issue e.g the tracing is activated each time we are running the `msaccess` program even though we have deactivated the log in odbc.

We are using an `msaccess`program that works as a frontend , that frontend is connecting to a Postgres database through an ODBC connection. The platform is Windows 7.

Below is the start of the content of the trace error.

```
c:\mylog_5072.log open error 5
[1128-0.000]ci=00000000 globals.extra_systable_prefixes = ''
[1128-0.000]exe name=MSACCESS
[1128-0.000][[SQLAllocHandle]][1128-0.000]**** in PGAPI_AllocEnv **
```

The tracing was set like this (see video below)

[image]

My colleague told me that the logging config might got stucked in `regedit`

I checked at the following below

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI]

This is what I've found

[image]

- Question: Would it be possible that ODBC logging instead of being switched off, is still on?

Answer (score 1):

After much wrangling, the thing to do is to reboot the machine / server.

As @Ben-N mentioned, `comm_log` and `debug` are both set to zero as you can see in the screen capture above.

So the regedit was not the issue

Finally, because `msaccess` created a lock file and I could not run `msaccess`, I've decided to reboot to get rid of that lock file.

Once the reboot was done, the change on ODBC was effective.

Dunno why , probably a bug.